# HTML email convert external style-sheet to inline-styles

Tags: python, html, css, email, inline-styles

I need to send HTML emails to users from python code. Some email clients don't allow external style-sheets, so styling needs to be inline.

What I want to do is to parse external CSS file(tiny css module), HTML email file and call an `inline_styles()` fn. This `inline_styles()` fn selects the element based on CSS selector and places the CSS declarations in style attribute.

How can I select elements by CSS selector to add styles to them?

Answer (score 5):

<s>I believe virtually all email clients have support for `<style>`</s>. [Premailer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/premailer) is your friend.

Comment: Gmail for one is notorious for ignoring style tag: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @Variant thanks for the awesome link and pointing out how grossly wrong I was.